# A specific question in $G_2$ geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, holonomy

Let's take a closed $G_2$ manifold $(M,\Phi)$. $\Phi$ denoting the three-form which defines the $G_2$ structure on $M$. Let's take a closed two form $\theta\in\Omega^2(M).$ Is
\begin{align}
d(\theta_{\Omega^2_7})\wedge (*\Phi)=0?
\end{align}

$\Omega^2_7$ comes from the splitting of $\Omega^2$ into $7$ and $14$ dimensional subspaces. $\theta_{\Omega^2_7}$ is the part of $\theta$ which lies in the $7$-dimensional part.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\Phi$ is closed and co-closed?  If so, then, yes, what you have written is an identity.  If not, then it depends on the torsion of the $\mathrm{G}_2$-structure.

Comment: Thanks, yes I see it now.  All I have to use is $d(\theta_{\Omega^2_7})=-d(\theta_{\Omega^2_{14}})$ and $\theta_{\Omega^2_{14}}\wedge *\Phi=0.$

Comment: Yes, but you do have to at least assume that the $14$-piece of $\mathrm{d}({*}\Phi)$ vanishes in order to draw your conclusion.